# Is it officially reccomened to add a totally new phtml template file in a theme, one which doesn't override an existing template?

Tags: magento2, theme, template, phtml

Magento's documentation (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-walkthrough.html#template-customization-walkthrough) describes how to customise an existing template, by overriding it in your theme - copying the phtml from a core module into your theme then modify it.

It seems possible to add a **new** phtml template with a custom theme, **not override** an existing template. This can be achieved by creating the new phtml template in the `Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/my_new_template.phtml`, where `my_new_template.phtml` was not an existing template in `Magento_Theme`. Then to get that new template onto the page by using a layout file, referencing that new template and giving it a standard block, like this

```
<referenceContainer name="some.reference">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="my.new.template" template="Magento_Theme::my_new_template.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

The key bit here is that `my_new_template.phtml` did not exist previously and is not being overridden. Its new.

Is this a Magento sanctioned method of adding a new template to a page from within a theme?

The [docs][1] I linked to at the start of this question do say

> To add a new template in a theme:
>
> Add a template in your theme directory according to the template storing convention.
>
> Assign your template to a block in the corresponding layout file.

But there is no example and its unclear and I'm not sure I've interpreted this correctly.

Is this recommend by Magento?

[1]: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-walkthrough.html#template-customization-walkthrough)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is how you are supposed to add a new template.

Comment: Can you point me toward anything in the official docs to support this? Any examples of core code doing it?

Comment: The information you've taken from the docs supports this. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-walkthrough.html#template-customization-walkthrough

Comment: And you can see this is pretty much every layout XML file within Magento - https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

Comment: The only difference is you're using "Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as a class, this is optional as the class will default to this so you may struggle to find it being used.

Comment: Also, following the core is not always good practice as Magento code itself often follows bad practices

Comment: The link you've provided shows phtml templates begin added within the context of a module. I understand that if you're building a new module, then this is how you add your phtml files to the system. My question is about doing this within a theme. That is, adding a new  template to the system within a theme, not a new template within a module and not overriding an existing module's template. There are no examples of this in the core (Luma theme) and the docs are unclear on the issue.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's in a module or a theme, the way you add a template is the same minus the view/frontend directories. There isn't any new way of adding templates that only works in the theme. The official docs aren't very useful for many things so you'll need to trust the community to answer many questions such as this.